# struct unable to define new type and structs within structs

Tags: c, types, struct

I have the following C code.

It is supposed to create a house type and a room type. However It seems the room type is not being recognised because I can't create functions of type room.

After the code is the compiler error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//create type Room.
struct Room
{
    float width;
    float length;
    float height;
    char *name;
};

//create type House.
struct House
{
    char *address;
    /*Rooms in house are an array of pointers. Each pointer to a Room.*/
    struct Room *rooms[10];
};

//protype functions.
void printHouse (struct House house);
Room createRoom(char *name, float width, float length, float height);


int main()
{
    //create house h.
    struct House h;
    h.address = "10 Palace Road";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        h.rooms[i] = NULL;

    //create a room (hall) without use of createRoom. Successful.
    struct Room hall;
    hall.width = 10;
    hall.length = 12;
    hall.height = 9;
    hall.name = "Hall";

    h.rooms[0] = &hall;
    h.rooms[1] = &createRoom("lounge", 20, 20, 9);


    printHouse(h);

    return 0;
}

Room createRoom(char *name, float width, float length, float height)
{
    struct Room r;
    r.width = width;
    r.length = length;
    r.height = height;
    r.name = name;

    return r;
}

//prints contents of the house. Working okay.
void printHouse (struct House house)
{
printf("%s",house.address);
printf("\n\r\n\r");
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if (house.rooms[i] != NULL)
    {
        struct Room r = *house.rooms[i];
        printf("Room #%d: %s", i, r.name);
    }
}

}
```

I am getting the following, that I don't know how to fix, during compile. Could anyone tell me what to do here and tell me why Room is not being recognised as a type?.

```
gcc -std=c99 -c -Wall -ggdb   -c -o struct.o struct.c
struct.c:24:1: error: unknown type name ‘Room’
struct.c: In function ‘main’:
struct.c:40:15: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
struct.c: At top level:
struct.c:49:1: error: unknown type name ‘Room’
struct.c: In function ‘createRoom’:
struct.c:57:2: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct Room’ but ‘int’ was expected
struct.c:58:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make: *** [struct.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You didn't even post the code in which the first error is present...

Comment: Really? I posted everything apart from my makefile.

Comment: @urbanslug, just so you know, you can initialize a `struct` in a single declaration (almost like you would initialize an array).

Comment: How many bytes would you expect `printf("\n\r\n\r");` to print? You might want to check that...

Answer (score 2):

This function:

```
Room createRoom(char *name, float width, float length, float height);
```

Should be declared and defined like so:

```
struct Room createRoom(char *name, float width, float length, float height);
^^^^^^
```

On this line:

```
h.rooms[1] = &createRoom("lounge", 20, 20, 9);
```

you are taking the address of a temporary which you are not allowed to do. You could potentially use a temporary variable like so:

```
h.rooms[0] = &hall;
struct Room hall2 = createRoom("lounge", 20, 20, 9);
h.rooms[1] = &hall2 ;
```

although that is not a pretty solution, you may want to consider having `createRoom` dynamically allocate a `Room` and return a `Room*`. You are also assigning string literals to `name` and `address` which could come back to bit you later on, you may also want to consider dynamically allocating space for those variables and copying using something like `strcpy` or `strncpy`.

Comment: I tried passing the instance of a room like `struct Room r;` and then `h.rooms[1] = &createRoom(r, "lounge", 20, 20, 9);` in the function `struct Room createRoom(struct Room r, char *name, float width, float length, float height);` but it didn't work. A little help.

Comment: Based on how you intend to store them, the function should be `struct Room *createRoom(...)`, and instead of `struct Room r;`, do `struct Room *r=malloc(sizeof struct Room);`. Then you can return your pointer to allocated object, and store the pointer in your array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You also can change your declaration from

```
struct Room
{
    float width;
    float length;
    float height;
    char *name;
};
```

to

```
typedef struct Room
{
    float width;
    float length;
    float height;
    char *name;
} Room;
```

and similar for House.